# C++: Invalid entry skipping over my pogram pause?

Tags: c++, validation, input, switch-statement

Newbie here! I have written a simple menu driven program. Since it's for an assignment, I've placed a pause asking for user input before completely terminating the program and disappearing.

I've used a switch statement for the menu and whenever the user inputs a valid entry, it completes that entrie's function, displays the "Program Ended", displays "Enter any key to exit" message and awaits input before ending.

However, when I enter invalid input, the switch statement displays the default statement, displays "Program Ended" as well as "Enter any key to exit." but does not wait for user input and instead ends on its own.

I'm thinking that somehow a value is being stored in my pause integer, but I don't understand from where? Is it the user input that's being left in the buffer?

What would be the best way to fix this?

```
    switch (choice)
    {
            case 1: commFail(); break;
            case 2: engFail(); break;
            case 3: icing(); break;
            case 4: break;
    
            default: cout << "Invalid Entry.\n";
    }
 
    cout <<"Program ended.\n";
    cout <<"Enter any key to exit.\n";
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    return 0;
```

Comment: It's hard to be completely specific since you've only provided partial code.   But, if the user enters invalid input, there's a good chance (depending on how your other code reads input, which you haven't shown) that the stream is left in an error state or some of that invalid input is left in the stream buffer waiting to be read.   Either way, `cin >> a` can immediately fail, and not wait for input.   Generally, the solution to this type of problem is not to use formatted I/O - instead read data as a string (or one character at a time) and parse it for the values you need.

Comment: Before the portion of the program I included there's just a simple cin statement to get the user input and store it in a variable "choice" which is then passed to the switch statement.
Thank you for sharing all of that information and helping me understand what's going on!
 I'll look into a better way to pause my program.